# Remove 20% from stored price in MySQL field, using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a site with a client they've just realised that they've given me all of their prices inclusive of sales tax (20%) - is there a way for me to iterate through the price fields and update the value to remove 20% from every entry? In a sql query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE foo SET price = price / 1.2
```

**Update:** As about rounding, you have [ROUND(X, D)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round).

Comment: +1 - Of three answers, only one knows how to do this correctly.  Shame on the others for typing before thinking.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to fill in the blanks with the actual table name and price field, but that's basically all you'd have to do.

```
UPDATE table SET price = price / 1.2
```

(edited to fix my math)

If you want to make sure you only have 2 decimal places, you could use MySQL's [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function like this:

```
UPDATE table SET price = ROUND(price / 1.2, 2)
```

You might consider changing the data type of the `price` field to a [`DECIMAL(9,2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) type, depending on how high your prices might ever get.

Comment: I think it's `incorrect_price = 1.2 * correct_price`. So `SET price = price / 1.2` actually.

Comment: Furthermore, `price - (price * 0.2)` is just an obfuscated variation of plain `price * 0.8`.

Comment: Whoops, morning math.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Looks like the price=price/1.2 method works out correct - just out of interest, do you know if this will leave me with many decimal places? If so can I limit to just two?